# get Y value of quadratic curve given the max height of the curve

Tags: javascript, math

When **Y** is **100** the maximum height of the curve will be (+/-) **60**. I need a way to calculate **Y** when I have the maximum height of the curve.

**Code:**

**point1** and **point2** have x, y and z coordinates

```
this.drawLine = function(point1, point2) {
    context = this.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.getX(point1), this.getY(point1));
    point3 = {
        x: ( point1.x + point2.x ) / 2,
        y: ( point1.y + point2.y ) / 2,
        z: ( point1.z + point2.z ) / 2
    }
    context.quadraticCurveTo( this.getX(point3), this.getY(point3) + point3.z * 0, this.getX(point2), this.getY(point2));
    context.stroke();
}
```

I need the line of the curve to hit the coordinates of **point3** instead of it not reaching the coordinates.

Comment: Please consider adding a little more information to your question. If you aren't sure of what else to add... perhaps a little context would be good. Do you have a specific equation that you are using to draw the curve?

Answer (score 0):

There are still many possible curves with the same maximums. Therefore, you cannot isolate a single curve to figure out your Y value.

I would suggest finding a way to obtain more information about your curve such as a point, property or relation.

Check out these links:
http://www.personal.kent.edu/~bosikiew/Algebra-handouts/quad-extval.pdf 
http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/graphing-quadratic-equations-using-transformations.html

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer: [here](http://codetheory.in/calculate-control-point-to-make-your-canvas-curve-hit-a-specific-point/)

```
this.drawLine = function(point1, point2, style) {
    context = this.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(this.getX(point1), this.getY(point1));
    point3 = {
        x: ( point1.x + point2.x ) / 2,
        y: ( point1.y + point2.y ) / 2,
        z: ( point1.z + point2.z ) / 2
    }
    context.strokeStyle = style;
    x = this.getX(point3) * 2 - ( this.getX(point1) + this.getX(point2) ) / 2;
    y = this.getY(point3) * 2 - ( this.getY(point1) + this.getY(point2) ) / 2;
    context.quadraticCurveTo( x, y, this.getX(point2), this.getY(point2));
    context.stroke();
}
```